# Grab image of workspace 2 while in workspace 1 using Pyscreenshot

Tags: python

I am on Ubuntu 18.04, I want to take a screenshot of Workspace 2 while I am in 1 without changing to workspace2. I want to use a Python script/command.

If a certain event happens I want to move to workspace2.

Is taking a screenshot like this possible?